# SSL error on installing cucumber in windows 7

Tags: ssl, cucumber, calabash

When I try to install cucumber for calabash andriod testing, it gives me the error below.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A
```

command used: `gem install cucumber`